# Serialization and SOLID principles

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, solid

I have several configuration structures that can be JSON serialized and deserialized as follows:

```cpp
namespace config
{

struct Foo
{
    std::string   hostname  {};
    std::string   ip_address{};
    std::uint32_t port      {};
};

JSON::Object serialize( config::Foo const& foo )
{
    // ...
}

config::Foo deserialize( JSON::Object const& object )
{
    // ...
}

} // namespace config
```

and in the `serialization::JSON` namespace I have main `serialize` and `deserialize` functions that call specific config `serialize` and `deserialize` functions:

```cpp
template <typename T>
Object serialize( T const& obj, Allocator& allocator )
{
    return serialize( obj, allocator );
}

// ...
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this a good design that follows SOLID principles (specifically Single Responsibility Principle)? Would making `serialize`/`deserialize` member functions of configuration structures break SRP or any of other SOLID principles? What in case adding XML serialization/deserialization?
2. One thing that drives me towards making `serialize`/`deserialize` member functions is that I would need to use template specializations to make `deserialize` function free function for each configuration structure.
3. If I have `config::App` configuration structure, but I also have main `App` class, would naming configuration structure `config::AppConfig` make more sense, even though `config` part repeats?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In short

You are right, there is a problem in this design.  But it's about dependency inversion and not single responsibility.

### More details

**SRP is about having a [one and only one reason to change](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html)**. Changes in the hidden implementation details of another module do not matter, as long as its public interface stays stable:

- `config::Foo` only needs to change if the configuration information changes.
- In the `config` namespace, `serialize()` and `serialize()` only need to change if `Foo` changes, so if configuration information chances, assuming they use `JSON::Object`'s public interface and do not rely on its internals.
- In the `serialization::JSON` namespace, `serialize()` and `serialize()` do not need to change due to change in `config` thanks to templates.

Therefore, there seem to be no issue in view of a single reason to change.

The real problem in your design is that you have a concrete implementation of serialization based on `JSON::Object`, and you build the rest on this fundament. This is why introducing a second way of serialization (e.g. XML in addition of JSON) causes a trouble.

**This dependency to a concrete implementation is both undesirable and avoidable.**  You therefore should consider the [**dependency inversion principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

- Define an abstract interface for a serialization object/service.
- Then rewrite your `config` to depend on this abstraction.
- And then find some way to inject the serialization service you want when you want it.

This could be at runtime using a strategy pattern (which would include a factory to instantiate the serialization objects). In C++, this could be at compile-time, using the metaprogramming equivalent to the strategy patter,  the [policy based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design).  By the way, the [boost:serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) could be an interesting source of inspiration if you're looking for an example of good serialization design.